# having trouble using the console.writeline overload function to pass arrays

Tags: c#, .net, overloading, console.writeline

beginner here :

I'm I misunderstanding the use of the overloaded function?

```
namespace Grades
{
    class Program
    {
        private static object mike;
        private static object gus;
        private static object julio;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object[] names = new object[3];
            names[1] = mike;
            names[0] = gus;
            names[2] = julio;

            WriteAnswer(" you're cool ",  names );
        }

        static void WriteAnswer(string description, params  object[] result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(description + " " + result);   
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
you're cool System.Object[]
```

I was under the impression that the output would be:

```
you're cool gus mike julio
```

Or:

```
you're cool gus 
you're cool mike 
you're cool julio
```

Comment: Your impression is indeed wrong, but without knowing *why* you believe a false thing, it is difficult to concisely disabuse you of your false belief. Can you tell us more about why you believe that the expected behaviour differs from the actual behaviour?

Comment: For example, it seems like you believe that putting an object in an array puts the *variable name used to store the reference* in the array, but it does no such thing.  In your case `gus` will be `null`, and so that is what is stored in the array.

Comment: For example, it seems like you believe that concatenating an array to a string prints the contents of the array; it does not. It prints the type of the array.  There *is* a case where passing an array to `WriteLine` prints the contents of the array, but this isn't it.  Were you expecting that?

Comment: My point is: there are any number of false beliefs you might have, all of which should be disabused, but we don't know what they are. Edit the question to say more about what you think this program should do and why, and we can explain where you're wrong.

Comment: Just to add that what you have done is not an _overload_ of `Console.WriteLine`. You have effectively wrapped the functionality of it in another function, not overloaded it.

Comment: Also, you might say why you make your method a `params` method -- a *variadic* method, to use the jargon -- but then did not use that fact in your program. Can you say why you are calling a variadic method in its normal form, not its expanded form? Was this intentional?

Comment: yes this is exactly what i was expecting : There is a case where passing an array to WriteLine prints the contents of the array, @EricLippert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the problem you're experiencing has nothing to do with the overloaded function of `Console.WriteLine`.

Rather.. you are creating `object` variables but not giving them any values to hold, so they're `null`.. so with your current code... it would end up with `"you're cool "`, and that's it because the variables that are **named** `mike`, `gus`, and `julio` don't actually contain any values.

---

**Solution One**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    private static object mike = "mike"; // give the variable a value to hold
    private static object gus = "gus"; // give the variable a value to hold
    private static object julio = "julio"; // give the variable a value to hold
    public static void Main()
    {
        object[] names = new object[3];
        names[1] = mike;
        names[0] = gus;
        names[2] = julio;
        WriteAnswer(" you're cool ", names);
    }

    static void WriteAnswer(string description, object[] result)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(description + string.Join(",", result));
    }
}
```

I have edited your code in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PAcgWg)

---

**Solution 2**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    private static object mike = "mike"; // give the variable a value to hold
    private static object gus = "gus"; // give the variable a value to hold
    private static object julio = "julio"; // give the variable a value to hold
    public static void Main()
    {
        object[] names = new object[3];
        names[1] = mike;
        names[0] = gus;
        names[2] = julio;
        WriteAnswer(" you're cool ", names);
    }

    static void WriteAnswer(string description, object[] result)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(description + result[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jGUj6Q).

Comment: If this helps, please mark my answer as accepted so that this question can be seen as answered.

Comment: @jz_17 you're welcome.  just mark either my answer or Eric's as accepted (click the checkmark next to either of our answers) to show that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 3):

As M12's answer points out, you are not ever assigning values to your variables, so they'll always be null. Plainly that has to be fixed first.  To answer your actual concern though:

> I was expecting : There is a case where passing an array to WriteLine prints the contents of the array

Let's make some modifications to your program and then discuss how `WriteLine` works. We'll make an array of strings, and initialize its contents:

```
string[] names = { "Gus", "Mike", "Julio" };
```

Now, what are our options for `WriteLine` and what do they do? Suppose you have

```
Console.WriteLine("you're cool " + names);
```

What happens?

First, `"you're cool" + names` is analyzed to determine that it is an addition of a string and an object, so this becomes:

```
string temp = String.Concat("you're cool ", names.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

(Aside: it is not *exactly* that; do you see why?)

Now we must determine what `names.ToString()` does.  It returns a string giving the type of the array.  If you want instead to create a string that joins together the contents, use `string.Join`.

What about the variadic overloads of `WriteLine`?  What if instead we called

```
Console.WriteLine("you're cool ", names);
```

The formal parameter types of the applicable `WriteLine`s are:

```
(string, object)
(string, params object[])
```

So there are three possibilities:

1. Call `(string, object)` with the array as the object.
2. Call `(string, object[])` with the array as the `object[]`. (This is legal in C# because of *unsafe array covariance*.)
3. Call `(string, object[])` in the expanded form: that is, create a new `object[1] {names}` and pass that.

C# rejects the third option: a variadic method applicable in its normal form is always better than the expanded form.

C# rejects the first option because `object` is more general than `object[]`.

Therefore C# calls the second overload.  Now read the documentation for that overload; what do you think it will do, given the proposed *format string* and *format arguments*?